# Unable to update a column from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update the `unitcost` column of the `[Order Details]` table with the value from the `unitcost` column of the `Products` table in SQL Server.

This is my SQL query:

```
UPDATE dbo.[Order Details]
SET dbo.[Order Details].UnitCost = dbo.Products.UnitCost
FROM dbo.[Order Details]
INNER JOIN dbo.Products ON dbo.[Order Details].ProductID = dbo.Products.ProductID
```

I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'dbo', Expecting "("

This refers to the `dbo` at `SET dbo.[Order Details].UnitCost`.

Comment: The join syntax looks correct, which means the problem is something else.  See if you can select from each table using the exact `dbo.` syntax in your current query.

Comment: That is proper syntax.  You have something else going on.

Answer (score 2):

When using a `JOIN` inside an `UPDATE`, I recommend to always use **table alias** to make things clear. Also, since the `UPDATE` really can only apply to **one table**, there's no need to use that alias in the column to be set.

Try this:

```
UPDATE od
SET UnitCost = p.UnitCost
FROM dbo.[Order Details] od
INNER JOIN dbo.Products p ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
```